# Magento credit card statement shows "store id 1"

Tags: magento, transactions, stripe-payments

I am using Magento with the netgains stripe module, everything is working fine.  However when an order is processed the credit card statement shows the transaction as affiliated to "store id 1" how can i change this so the store name is displayed instead of this store id 1 information on the credit card statement

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may have figured out the answer to this now but if you haven't I can shed some light.

In app/code/local/Netgains/Stripe/Model/Stripe.php on Line 146 you'll see this:

```
        $storeId = 'Store Id'.' '.Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
```

You can change 'Store Id' to the name of your site/company and it will then show up on the customer's statement descriptor.